# When send()/recv() fails. Where does the socket stands?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, send, recv

Suppose I have a socket which I have created by the `socket()` system call. After that I did a `connect()` and started sending and receiving data.

Similarly, on the other side,  a socket was created with the `socket()` system call, and then `bind()`, `listen()` and `accept()` were called. Then this side also started communicating.

Now lets suppose one of the `send()` (and accordingly `recv()` on the other side) fails.

What I want to where would that socket stand after the fail?

To communicate again, should I create the socket again and do `connect()` (`bind()`, `listen()` and `accept()` on the other side) or I can try `send()` and `recv()` again? And additionally, what is the best thing to be done in such a scenario?

**NOTE:** We do not know what is the reason for the `send()`/`recv()` to fail. It can be anything from a physical wire break to the other side refusing (maybe using iptables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What to do depends entirely on why `send` or `recv` failed.

When an error is detected, check the value of `errno` to determine the reason.  For example, if the error code is `EAGAIN` you would attempt the operation again, and if the error code is `ECONNRESET` you would need to reconnect.

See the man pages for [`send`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send) and [`recv`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) for more details on what errors may be returned and what you should do about them.

Comment: Then a recovery from a broken network would result in a check for all the return values and then the steps to be taken accordingly?

Comment: @Haris The one you most likely want to check is if `send` returns -1 and `errno` is `ECONNRESET`.  For any other value, it should be safe to try again.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. That helped.